# How to add a command line code generator to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, msbuild, code-generation

I'm working on a project that uses code generation to generate C# classes using a command line tool from a text-based description. We are going to start using these descriptions for javascript too.

Currently these classes are generated and then checked in, however, I would like to be able to make the code generate automatically so that any changes are propagated to both builds.

The step that is run manually is:

```
servicegen.exe -i:MyService.txt -o:MyService.cs
```

When I build I want MSBuild/VS to first generate the CS file then compile it. It is possible to do this using, by modifying the `csproj`, perhaps using a MSBuild Task with `Exec`, `DependentUpon` & `AutoGen`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antlr has an [example of a process](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Integration+with+Development+Environments) that can be used to add generated code to a project. This has the advantage of showing the files that are generated nested under the source file, although it is more complex to add.

You need add an item group with the file to be generated from, for example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ServiceDescription Include="MyService.txt"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then add the cs file to be generated to the ItemGroup containing the rest of the source code.

```
<ItemGroup>
  ...
  <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  ...etc..
  <Compile Include="MyService.txt.cs">
    <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    <DependentUpon>MyService.txt</DependentUpon>  <!--note: this should be the file name of the source file, not the path-->      
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

And then finally add the build target to execute the code generation (using % to execute the command for each item in the ItemGroup). This could be put into a separate file, so that it can be included from many projects.

```
<Target Name="GenerateService">
  <Exec Command="servicegen.exe -i:%(ServiceDescription.Identity) -o:%(ServiceDescription.Identity).cs" />
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>GenerateService;$(BuildDependsOn)</BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 6):

Normally I would recommend a pre-build command be placed in a pre-build event, but since your command line tool will be creating C# classes needed for compiling, this should be done [in the BeforeBuild target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the .csproj file. The reason for this is because MSBuild looks for the files it needs to compile between the time BeforeBuild is called and the time when PreBuildEvent is called in the overall process (you can see this flow in the Microsoft.Common.targets file used by MSBuild).

Call the Exec task from within the BeforeBuild target to generate the files:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command="servicegen.exe -i:MyService.txt -o:MyService.cs" />
</Target>
```

See the [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) MSDN documentation for more details about specifying different options for the Exec task.